# Date Format in DataGrid easyui

Tags: sql-server, date, datagrid, date-format, jquery-easyui

I have a table (using datagrid easyui) with SQL server connection.
My problem is the date doesn't appear in the table and only display [object Object] in column of datagrid without any error message.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community Wiki answer based on edit from OP's original question:

I use convert date function in SQL Server like `SELECT theDate = CONVERT (varchar, theDate, 106) FROM table`.

The number 106 used to display date format `dd mon yyyy`.